# Why does "flex-wrap: wrap" break "align-items"?

Tags: css, flexbox

(I'm using Chrome v.39+)

I'm trying to use the flex-wrap property to stack child divs both horizontally and vertically, but I'm seeing some very strange behaviors. For example, if there's 3 child divs and the last is given a width of 100% (causing it to wrap) there will be unwanted gaps introduced.

Sometimes I can force the first 2 divs to honor `align-items: stretch` by giving them `height: 100%` or `height: calc(100% - 1px)`, other times they won't stretch passed the mysterious gap, and sometimes they'll even disappear all together if I try to force them to stretch.

Here's a [simplified example of the problem](http://cssdeck.com/labs/k4r1cama). They grey shouldn't be visible.

Why are these gaps appearing in flex-wrapped divs and how can I prevent them?

Comment: Could you please sketch what you expect or at least descibe it? I only read "unwanted", "strange behaviour", "not expected" - maybe your expectation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray area is still visible at the bottom because you set a height on the parent container.

If you don't want to see that gray area, remove the height from the container and add a fixed height that you require on one of the elements in the first row

**[DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/4lqjfrbx)**

```css
.a {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: #999;
}
.b {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.c {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.d {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.c {
  width: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.d {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='d'></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** If you want to avoid fixed dimensions - just remove the `height:10px` from the red div.

This will ensure that there are no gaps and that each row has equal height

**[DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/45svsa75)**

Comment: Thanks for the visual example. I intentionally set `align-self: flex-end` to demonstrate that the last div isn't preventing the other 2 from stretching vertically...as you pointed out, the unwanted grey is still visible regardless. I'm using flexbox partly to avoid hard coding dimensions onto child divs. In many situations, I also don't wan't to hard code dimensions on the parent either (the parent could also be a flex child). Is fixed dimensions the only way to avoid gaps?

Comment: The gap was only caused in the first place because you set a fixed height on the red div. Now that you say that you want to **avoid fixed dimensions** - just remove the `height:10px` from the red div and see that there are no gaps http://cssdeck.com/labs/45svsa75